# Load csv data to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

I have a csv file containing entries as follows:

```
a,10
b,20
c,30
d,40
```

In JavaScript, I want to assign this csv file to a variable lets say x as follow:

```
x = [
 ['a',10],
 ['b',20],
 ['c',30],
 ['d',40]
]
```

Can someone tell me how i can do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript code to parse CSV data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data).  Please search before asking.  That was the first result for "javascript csv".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your CSV is really that simple, you just need two splits and a loop:

```
var rows = "a,10\nb,20\nc,30\nd,40".split('\n');
var x = [];
for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
    x.push(rows.split(','));
}
```

A shorter version:

```
var x = "a,10\nb,20\nc,30\nd,40".split('\n').map(function(val) {
    return val.split(',');
});
```